# Limit Action to once per Minute

Tags: c#

```
 if (player.Stars < 20 && text[0] != '/')
        {
        player.SendInfo("You may only talk once per minute.");
            return;
        }
```

What is the easiest way to add to the `If` so that if a player tries sending more then 1 message in a minute, it gets stopped?

Comment: Choose whichever you like `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` `System.Threading.Timer` `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more information. Solutions would be different for single-player and multiplayer games and for distributed applications. For a networked application, this would require considerably more than a single `if`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this would be to store some sort of timestamp on your `player` object and check against it in the `if` statement. You'd also want to make sure that it gets set later on in the function (or somewhere else) in order for it to work correctly.

Here's an example of what this could look like (`LastTalked` is the name of the timestamp, but you can obviously call it whatever you want):

```
if (player.Stars < 20 && text[0] != '/' && DateTime.UtcNow - player.LastTalked < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
{
    player.SendInfo("You may only talk once per minute.");
    return;
}

player.LastTalked = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Note that this is based solely on information available in your question; there may be other considerations to take into account.

Comment: Careful with recommending `DateTime.Now`. It's only correct in limited scenarios and probably rarely-to-never in games.

Comment: @xxbbcc What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about the question. Games usually keep track of their own virtual time so if the game loop is stopped, the game world's time stops as well. Real-world `DateTime` would interfere with this and this could lead to various problems. If this is distributed software, times should be in UTC, not local times.

Comment: What Donut said, what would you suggest? I was thinking of doing this something like this: After the first initial message, it starts a countdown, and if the countdown != 0 then display the error, but if it does then go on with it.

Comment: This is a multiplayer game. How would I use UTC?

Comment: @DylanGM If this is a networked multiplayer game then every time you type DateTime.Now you're creating a bug. Your players could be in any time zone (different from your server's time zone). A single local time is guaranteed to introduce bugs.

Comment: Can you give me your thoughts on how I could use it without creating a bug? Or do you suggest a different way?

Comment: You can just use `DateTime.UtcNow`, I've updated my answer. You're not *necessarily* going to create a bug by using `DateTime.Now` (for example, if this value is only ever going to be used locally on the client). Although it could make things easier by just always using UTC.

Comment: @DylanGM Not based on your current question. You should edit it with a lot more detail - is this on the server or on a client? Who keeps track of 'official time' for the entire game? Is this in-game or out-of-game (like chat)? This is a fairly broad problem and there are many possible solutions.

Comment: @Donut Sorry for hijacking your answer - I didn't mean to do that. You're technically correct in saying _not necessarily going to create a bug by using DateTime.Now_ but the chances are pretty high. :)

Comment: This is Server side, not Client, and the time is kept Server side.

Comment: @xxbbcc Not a problem. Sounds like UTC's probably a good idea in this case.

Comment: Got it to work with what you said. If you would, upvote my post so I don't get banned? :( I don't know what I keep doing wrong but every question I ask gets downvoted.

Comment: @DylanGM You won't get banned.  To elaborate on the downvotes though (not from me), they were most likely because you didn't provide enough information in the question to provide an accurate answer.  You provided these two pieces of information in your comments: `This is a multiplayer game.`; `This is Server side, not Client, and the time is kept Server side.` - both of these details together provide the necessary context to make the question a lot more answerable, and I would guess that had you provided them in the question, you'd have not received the downvotes.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @DylanGM Don't get discouraged! Writing a good question is harder than most people think and it takes effort and practice to do it well. There are some helpful guidelines provided here that might be useful when asking questions in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should store last message time, and compare current time with it.

If difference will be less then 1 minute -- block `SendInfo`